# The Concept of being a "Prime" in the Transformers film universe

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, optimus-prime, transformers-revenge-of-the-fallen, megatron

In *Revenge of the Fallen* we come to know that Optimus is a **Prime**. But if Megatron is Optimus's brother, wouldn't that make him a Prime too?

So my question is basically this, is Prime some sort of bloodline (ummm, oil-line?) amongst the Transformers, or is it a title?

Comment: it might also depend on how you define brother, as in actual relative or kinsman/countryman.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Speaking strictly about movie canon...

Regarding [The Primes](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Dynasty_of_Primes) (per TF wiki):

> Eons ago, the AllSpark created thirteen beings, the first Cybertronians, who had the ability to move between dimensions. [...]
>
> According to Jetfire, the Dynasty of Primes was formed by the first Thirteen Cybertronians. These beings could not transform, but they and their transforming descendants possessed powers beyond that of the average Cybertronian.

But not every Transformer is a "genetic" descendent of the Primes. The Primes were just the thirteen *originals* created.

> They soon realized that the AllSpark's power, though vast, was not infinite, and required the energy of stars to be replenished. Once a nearby star went nova, the AllSpark created a worker race, the Transformers, who would assist the Dynasty in replenishing the AllSpark.

[Sentinel Prime](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Sentinel_Prime_(ROTF)) was not one of the original thirteen. He was a direct descendant.

> Sentinel Prime was a direct descendant of the first Cybertronian, Primus, and was believed to be the last of the Primes.

In the movie continuity, [Optimus Prime](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Optimus_Prime_%28Movie%29) was originally named "Optimus". He and [Megatron](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Megatron_%28Movie%29) worked with Sentinel Prime.

> [Optimus] was the humble leader of Cybertron's science division, which studied the AllSpark, and were protected by Lord High Protector Megatron's military. [...]
>
> [Megatron] was once brothers-in-arms with Optimus and a student of Sentinel Prime, appointed to be Cybertron's Protector and commander of its Defense Force.

But there was more to Optimus than meets the eye. Optimus is actually a direct descendant of one of the Primes (Prima, to be specific).

> It was Optimus Prime's ancestor who finally vanquished the Fallen to another dimension in the battle for the Matrix of Leadership, but his orphaned descendant who was hidden away from the Fallen grew up with no knowledge of what he was.

Sentinel Prime told Optimus of his theories about Prime's lineage.

> Though Optimus was too humble to accept, not believing Sentinel's claims about his heritage, Megatron overheard their conversation and became jealous of his "brother."  Sentinel formulated another plan for Cybertron's future: it would be governed by Optimus's Science Division and Megatron's Defense Force. By having Optimus investigate the remains of the Primes' civilization, it would encourage him to believe in his lineage.

Eventually, Optimus finds proof that he is a descendant of a Prime. It is then that the other Autobots begin addressing him as such, and he becomes known as "Optimus Prime".

> Back at Burthov, he came upon Ratchet, Arcee, and Elita-One scanning the pieces of the other artifacts. Arcee then discovered that the pieces all contained the same symbol on them, and that the same symbol was on Optimus' head. Ratchet declared that the symbol was proof of the Dynasty of Primes, and it indicated Optimus himself was a Prime. Ratchet and the other Autobots began to dub him "Optimus Prime" [snip] Optimus also informed Sentinel of the marking on his head that proved he was right all along: he was a Prime too.

Megatron was not a direct descendant of a Prime. He was jealous of Optimus.

> But Megatron resented his comrade, knowing he was a Prime and therefore Sentinel's favored son.

Even still, Optimus and Megatron led Cybertron for a time.

> For two generations, Optimus and Megatron ruled Cybertron together. The two personalities created a balance; Prime was fair while Megatron was firm.

In one of the comics, Barricade breaks the fourth wall and explains that the two are *not* actual "brothers" despite each one regarding the other as one.

> However, in the twelfth issue of Titan's Revenge of the Fallen comic, "Barricade" informed readers that Megatron and Optimus weren't related, the term "brother" was just because they'd known each other for so long.

Putting this all together, we've painted the picture that Optimus and Megatron were once close allies. They worked together under Sentinel to bring peace to Cybertron. While Optimus was a descendant of a Prime, Megatron was not. Still, from years of friendship and being allies, they considered each other as "brothers" despite not being "genetically" related.

Comment: awesome ... well written

Answer (score 5):

Prime is (for the most part) a title, and not one that is purely inherited. The details differ from *Transformers* continuity to the next, and the role isn't well defined in the movie universe, but basically a Prime is part military commander and part spiritual leader of the Autobots.

In the movie universe, a Prime is always descended from Primus who is the first Cybertronian. While Megatron is indeed descended from Primus, just as his brother is, he was not selected to be the leader of the Autobots so he is not considered a Prime though he carries the right blood/oil/energon.

Comment: In *Revenge of the Fallen*, Jetfire says, "So, you've met a Prime? Why, you must have met a great descendant." This puts more weight to the bloodline theory than just a who was selected as spiritual/military leader.

Comment: @phantom42 actually the opposite case could be made because he said "great" descendant, not just a generic descendant. That's essentially what this answer is saying, that not every descendant is a Prime, only the exceptional (great!) ones who become leaders of the Autobots.

Comment: Is the part about primus and megatron from the novelisation or from the comics?

Comment: @Thomas - It's from the novelizations I believe, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Optimus is a Prime, leader of the Autobots, and was created by Alpha Trion with his brother Ultra Magnus, who is not a Prime but they are real brothers. Primus had given the Matrix to Optimus so he could be the last of the Primes. Sentinel Prime was Optimus and Megatron's leader; but Megatron wasn't a Prime but a gladiator and was jealous of Optimus, and built an army up called the Decepticons, who want to invade Cybertron.

The Fallen was one of the thirteen Primes, his name used to be Megatronus.

The rest of the seven Primes were brothers of the Fallen, and related to Optimus Prime. Remember when Optimus and the Fallen were fighting, the Fallen said "Die like your brothers", to which Optimus replied "There were your brothers too".

To be honest Optimus is the strongest, most powerful and the smartest that is why Primus had turned him into Optimus Prime, the leader of the Autobots. Even though he died, he always gets back up and fights and he had fought with three strong Decepticons which he failed to defeat, but fought like a Prime.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. This seems like i could be an answer, do have any sources to back up your evidence. Also, I would recommend cleaning up some of the formatting to make the post more legible.

Answer (score -2):

I am speaking strictly off the site that I got this from:

> You may have heard that Optimus wasn’t a Prime, well, he wasn’t Optimus either, his name was Orion Pax and he worked as a clerk in the Iacon hall of records.
>
> Learning more about Cybertron’s past, he noticed corruption in high places. He then took interest in a gladiator named Megatronus, after one of the thirteen original Primes. He gathered followers, Soundwave chief among them. Orion considered Megatronus as a mentor to him and after Megatronus left the gladiator Orion, he saw fit to shorten his name.
>
> Now Megatron came up before the Primes and showed his true colors. He arrogantly demanded to be named the next Prime and wanted to rule Cybertron under his command, but Orion did not believe in vile and pain, the Sparks and minds of the Primes were moved by Orion’s words. For the first time since Cybertron’s Golden Age, there was someone worthy to be a Prime, but the only way to accomplish that was to earn the legendary Matrix of Leadership.
>
> Megatron was furious and heturned his followers into a band called Decepticons of whom waged war on Cybertron. Evil corrupted across Cybertron and soon spread to the very core of that planet. Orion adventured there, hoping to stop the ill effects, and before he knew it he was standing in front of their life giver Primus himself. Primus gave Orion the Matrix and at that very moment, the humbled Orion Pax soon became known as Optimus, the last of the Primes.

The background of the video was done in comic book slides so I think this was Baricade’s refrence to Optimus’s origin story.

Edit note: This is from Transformers: Prime, episode 26 "One shall rise: Part 3"

Comment: I have no idea where this is taken from, if someone does please edit the link in.

Comment: Should it say "and he", rather than "Andy"?